# CPU,Memory and disk I/O utilization for each query in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

How can we identify the exact CPU,Memory and disk I/O, when a query is executed. I am using mysql 5.7.20 community version. I am able to get only cpu details for session level by setting SET profiling=1. How can we identify all these details in global level for all the sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Using **IOTOP** command you can see CPU,Memory and disk I/O utilization for each query. For each query mysql generates an ID. You can find CPU,Memory and disk I/O utilization against your query ID.

How ever you may find more command in detail at http://www.dbatodba.com/db2/useful-aix-commands/monitor-cpu-mem-and-i-o-usage/

SET profiling = 100 
-- Now you can find query ID and running sql query by 
SHOW PROFILES; IF you want TO CHECK IN detail FOR ANY QUERY, run this QUERY- 
-- SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY QueryID; 
-- If you want to check CPU USAGE for any query, run this query- 
SHOW PROFILE CPU FOR QUERY QueryID;

Comment: Thank for information pankaj kumar. My doubt is does mysql stores these information in any tables or views?? Lets take an example I have ran a query before two days. How can I get the details like how much memory been utilized for the query when I had executed it.

Comment: SHOW PROFILES displays a list of the most recent statements sent to the server. The size of the list is controlled by the profiling_history_size session variable, which has a default value of 15. The maximum value is 100. Setting the value to 0 has the practical effect of disabling profiling.
Optional type values may be specified to display specific additional types of information:

Comment: -- ALL displays all information
-- BLOCK IO displays counts for block input and output operations
-- CONTEXT SWITCHES displays counts for voluntary and involuntary context switches
-- CPU displays user and system CPU usage times
-- IPC displays counts for messages sent and received
-- MEMORY is not currently implemented
-- PAGE FAULTS displays counts for major and minor page faults
-- SOURCE displays the names of functions from the source code, together with the name and line    number of the file in which the function occurs
-- SWAPS displays swap counts

Comment: Now set maximum profiling
SET profiling = 100
Now you can find query ID and running sql query by
 SHOW PROFILES;
If you want to check in detail for any query, run this query-
 SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY QueryID;
 If you want to check CPU USAGE for any query, run this query-
 SHOW PROFILE CPU FOR QUERY QueryID;

Answer (score 0):

Memory usage -- InnoDB has a common "buffer pool" where it *caches* blocks.  there is no metric for memory usage.  On the other hand, you can find out various statistics for all queries over a period of time by watching the `STATUS` values of `Innodb_%` grow.

For CPU time, I recommend turning on the "slowlog" with `long_query_time=0`.  That will rapidly fill disk with lots of details about every query, including the *elapsed* time.  Note that "elapsed" is more interesting that CPU vs I/O.

The slowlog gives you the best view into which queries you should work on improving.  Perhaps that is what you are really looking for?  Use either `pt-query-digest` or `mysqldumpslow -s t` to find the few "worst" queries.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: Re *"'elapsed' is more interesting than CPU vs I/O"*.  Question: When there are multiple active connections on a server, will "elapsed" time depend on server load? Do I need to test during a quiet period, to get an accurate sense of the cpu time actually consumed by each query?  I'll test it both during busy and quiet times, so I'll know then, but I thought it would be good for others to know "a priori" what "elapsed time" really measures.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - Yes, any other activity can impact the elapsed time.  If your CPU has 8 cores, you need 9 things running for that to have much effect.  If other queries are touching the same rows, etc, then locks can block one or the other.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - If you have a slowlog covering 1000 instances of a particular query, nearly all will have about the same elapsed time.  But a few may take 10 times as long.  If, for example, long_qiuery_time = 1 (second) and that query normally takes 0.2 sec, a _few_ instances of those 1000 will show up in the log.